# Angular js - order by not working on multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I am not able to sort by multi dimensional array using angular js filter, please find my code in the link below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DpZl1rAFHjjoG5OdF1Qc?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items|orderBy:items.node_id:1">{{item.node_id}}
        - {{item.basic.readable_date}}-{{item.node_id}}
      </li>

    </ul>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy` just works for `arrays`. Since you're using an `object` in `ng-repeat` - I'm quite surprised that this is possible - `orderBy` doesn't do anything.

Have a look at [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjbOf0Ennpv85Akh6hiG?p=preview).